# Missing required property 'Builder.<variant kind>'

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

```
public void getMaxMinPrice(String category, String subcategory) {

        var nativeQueryBuilder = new NativeQueryBuilder();

        nativeQueryBuilder.withQuery(queryBuilder ->
                queryBuilder.bool(boolBuilder ->
                        boolBuilder.must(mustBuilder -> {


                            if (category != null) {
                                mustBuilder.term(termBuilder -> termBuilder.field("category.keyword").value(category));
                            }

                            if (subcategory != null) {
                                mustBuilder.term(termBuilder -> termBuilder.field("subcategory.keyword").value(subcategory));
                            }

                            return mustBuilder;
                        })));

        nativeQueryBuilder.withAggregation("max_price", Aggregation.of(aggBuilder ->
                aggBuilder.max(maxBuilder -> maxBuilder.field("price"))));

        nativeQueryBuilder.withAggregation("min_price", Aggregation.of(aggBuilder ->
                aggBuilder.min(minBuilder -> minBuilder.field("price"))));
    }
```

The exception is thrown somewhere in the nativeQueryBuilder.withQuery method. I am using ElasticSearch Template.

Comment: This does not even compile, what is mustBuilder? And a the stacktrace on such problems as well.
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @P.J.Meisch I added the full method.

Answer (score 0):

This is not reproducible for me. I put your code in a small scratch program and added one more variable (`query`) to out a breakpoint on:

```java
import co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch._types.aggregations.Aggregation;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.NativeQueryBuilder;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var scratch = new Scratch();
        scratch.getMaxMinPrice("category", "subcategory");
    }

    public void getMaxMinPrice(String category, String subcategory) {

        var nativeQueryBuilder = new NativeQueryBuilder();

        nativeQueryBuilder.withQuery(queryBuilder -> queryBuilder.bool(boolBuilder -> boolBuilder.must(mustBuilder -> {

            if (category != null) {
                mustBuilder.term(termBuilder -> termBuilder.field("category.keyword").value(category));
            }

            if (subcategory != null) {
                mustBuilder.term(termBuilder -> termBuilder.field("subcategory.keyword").value(subcategory));
            }

            return mustBuilder;
        })));

        nativeQueryBuilder.withAggregation("max_price",
                Aggregation.of(aggBuilder -> aggBuilder.max(maxBuilder -> maxBuilder.field("price"))));

        nativeQueryBuilder.withAggregation("min_price",
                Aggregation.of(aggBuilder -> aggBuilder.min(minBuilder -> minBuilder.field("price"))));

        var query = nativeQueryBuilder.build();
        query.getQuery();

    }
}
```

Stopping at the line with `query.getQuery` and inspecting the `query` variable, everything is set up correct, no error:

[image]

So the error you see must be coming from somewhere else. I use the current released 5.0 version.

Put a debugger breakpoint on the exception creation and see where this error comes from.